# Error executing SVN Diff command in TeamCity

Tags: powershell, svn, teamcity

I'm trying to automate SVN -diff command through TeamCity. **Here is the command I put inside a powershell runner**

```
svn diff -r 22:26 https://myserver.com:8443/svn/rep-one/branches/Dev/myfolder --summarize --xml
```

I get the following error in the Build log -

> svn: E215004: Authentication failed and interactive prompting is disabled; see the --force-interactive option

When I execute the same command outside TeamCity in powershell window, it works just fine. How do I supply credentials to SVN command? I don't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html ? [password](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.password) and [username](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.username)?

Comment: Thanks. I somehow overlooked the options earlier.

Comment: If this is solved then @EtanReisner you should stick that in an answer, and Imaya you should mark as accepted.